# Text value in axis ticks using scaleBand()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a barg graph using SVGs. I am currently attempting to have my tick values as strings along my x-axis. In my case, the x-axis will represent colors (represented as strings). I have scales and I have axes. I want an x-axis which displays string values corresponding to each bar. How might I go about this?

```
[{
  "color":"blue",
  "num":"8"
},
{
  "color":"green",
  "num": "8"
},
{
  "color":"red",
  "num":"6"
},
{
  "color":"black",
  "num":"2"
},
{
  "color":"purple",
  "num":"3"
},
{
  "color":"gold",
  "num":"4"
},
{
  "color":"teal",
  "num":"1"
}];

 var arr = data.map(function(d){return d.color;});

        // create scale for X-AXIS (1) //
        var band = d3.scaleBand() //
        .domain(d3.range(data.length))
        .range([0,width])           
        .paddingInner(0.1);


        // DEFINE X AXIS
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(band)
         .tickValues(d3.range(data.length))
         .tickFormat(function(d,i) {return d.color;});

        // CREATE X-AXIS
        d3.select(location).append("g")
        .attr("class","axis") // set class for x-axis
        .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
        .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: *"Scale band's domain will not accept an array as its input"*... A scale **only** accepts an array as the input.

Comment: My question is how do I get my x axis ticks to present as strings? What modifications would I need to make to my work? Why are those modifications necessary? @Azmisov

Comment: @MichaelRamageMikeRamage D3 ticks are always strings, so it's not clear what's the issue here. How is your axis? What values do you have now, and what values do you want to show?

Comment: I would like each tick on my x-axis to represent a color, which is a string in my dataset. Therefore, each tick should have the color labeled for its corresponding bar.  @GerardoFurtado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
var band = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(data.length))
```

As you can see, you're passing just a bunch of numbers (I'd guess you're using them as indices) to the scale. Here they are:

```js
var data = [{
    "color": "blue",
    "num": "8"
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "num": "8"
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "num": "6"
  },
  {
    "color": "black",
    "num": "2"
  },
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "num": "3"
  },
  {
    "color": "gold",
    "num": "4"
  },
  {
    "color": "teal",
    "num": "1"
  }
];

console.log(d3.range(data.length))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Because of that, your axis will have just numbers (unless you do a cumbersome `tickFormat` acceding `data` again):

```js
var data = [{
    "color": "blue",
    "num": "8"
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "num": "8"
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "num": "6"
  },
  {
    "color": "black",
    "num": "2"
  },
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "num": "3"
  },
  {
    "color": "gold",
    "num": "4"
  },
  {
    "color": "teal",
    "num": "1"
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
  .range([20, 480]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
axis(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

The idiomatic solution is passing the **categorical variable** you want to depict in the data visualisation to the band scale. This seems to be a bar chart or a similar visualisation type, in which the `color` is the categorical variable. That being the case, pass it to the scale:

```
.domain(data.map(d => d.color))
```

Here is how the axis will be:

```js
var data = [{
    "color": "blue",
    "num": "8"
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "num": "8"
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "num": "6"
  },
  {
    "color": "black",
    "num": "2"
  },
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "num": "3"
  },
  {
    "color": "gold",
    "num": "4"
  },
  {
    "color": "teal",
    "num": "1"
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.color))
  .range([20, 480]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
axis(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

For 2021+ readers messing around with tick formatting on some data with multiple fields the previous [tickFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035574/text-value-in-axis-ticks-using-scaleband/55038479#55038479) solution is the way to go. It's a Bad Idea(TM) to bind your data domain to a label/text field like in the accepted solution.

In the given example it's fine because there are no duplicative labels but this can't be guaranteed in other scenarios. For example, if your data was describing US Counties - you'd have to handle all 31 instances of "Washington County".

The `domain` from on the axis should be the id field with the `tickFormat` handling the display.

```js
import { scaleBand } from "d3-scale";
import { axisBottom } from "d3-axis";

xLabels = [{id: 0001, label: somelabel}, ...]

const xScale = scaleBand()
  .domain(xLabels.map((d) => d.id))
  .rangeRound([0, 500])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickFormat(
    (d) => xLabels.find((l) => l.id === d).label
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your `tickFormat`, not the `scaleBand`. The format function should be something like:

```
.tickFormat((i) => { return data[i].color; });
```

I'm not sure what the `num` field in your data is supposed to represent, if relevant. Maybe you need to cleanup up your data representation to fit d3 better.